# Repeat PHP code

Tags: php

I have this code that I would like to know if there is an easier way to have it repeated. I have about 60 of these and I will always be adding more so it would be nice if someone could help me figure out a loop or something so that I won't have to manually add each one. Each of these is making a link to a download, so I am guessing I will probably have to use the variable name as the file name. The file name 01 Intro.mp3 is what tells where the download is, so I am guessing to make this work I would also have to change that to the variable name.

Here is the code I use to get the variable names.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultstwo))
    {
    extract($row);
    }
```

Here is the code that I would like to be repeated. I included two of them.

```
<?php
            if ($intro ==1) {
                $strKey = createKey();
                mysqli_query($resDB,"INSERT INTO downloads (downloadkey, file, expires) VALUES ('{$strKey}', '01 Intro.mp3', '".(time()+(60*60))."')");
                echo "<a href='download.php?key=$strKey'>Intro</a>";
            }
        ?>
        <?php
            if ($fightingfires ==1) {
                $strKey = createKey();
                mysqli_query($resDB,"INSERT INTO downloads (downloadkey, file, expires) VALUES ('{$strKey}', '02 Fighting Fires.mp3', '".(time()+(60*60))."')");
                echo "<a href='download.php?key=$strKey'>Fighting Fires</a>";
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: Save them in a separate file and include them wherever you need

Comment: php,html,sql..all in one is not good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest having some variables within the database if not already included, such as:

```
id,caption,filename
--------------------
1,Intro,01 Intro.mp3
2,Fighting Fires,02 Fighting Fires.mp3
```

Here is the SQL query for creating this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `music` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `caption` varchar(32),
  `filename` varchar(32),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uc_filename` (`filename`)
);
```

As well as some test data that you can also insert.

```
INSERT INTO `music`(`caption`,`filename`) VALUES('Intro','01 Intro.mp3'),('Fighting Fires','02 Fighting Fires.mp3');
```

Assuming the user table follows the current format:

```
id,username,intro,fightingfires
-------------------------------
1,michael,1,NULL
2,dave,NULL,NULL
```

I believe that it should be altered to show this instead:

```
id,username,music_id
--------------------
1,michael,1,
2,dave,NULL
```

The structure of this table can be written as:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `username` varchar(32),
 `music_id` int(11),
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `music_id` (`music_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `users_music_id_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`music_id`) REFERENCES `music` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Now when a music row is deleted from the music table, any users wishing to download that music will also be removed.

Try to query the database like this now:

```
$resultstwo=$mysqli->query("SELECT `music_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username`='michael'");
```

Change the username based on which user is logged in, but I imagine you have that under control.

Then you can manage the data better like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultstwo)) {
    $strKey = createKey();
    mysqli_query($resDB,"INSERT INTO downloads (downloadkey, file, expires) VALUES ('{$strKey}', '".$row['filename']."', '".(time()+(60*60))."')");
    echo "<a href='download.php?key=$strKey'>".$row['caption']."</a>";
    break;
}
```

Then you can better manage downloading of music by adding or deleting columns from the table above.

Comment: I understand what you mean and I understand your while loop code. However I am not sure how I should setup the database to make it work your way. Do I need to setup a different table, because right now all the variables are stored in the same table as the username so that I can update the variable where the username is?

Comment: also how do I make it only give a download link if the variable is set to 1

Comment: What does the table of the query '$resultstwo' look like? By the looks of it, it seems that there are columns within the table called 'intro' and 'fightingfires'. I would highly recommending creating a separate table that manages the list of music available on your website.

Comment: I see, so does the user table include columns called 'intro' and 'fightingfires'? If so, wouldn't it be better to have what they want to download as a column, and that column referring to the music table?

Comment: I got it working and I have used the table you created. However this is for a user system so each user will have different songs available. So I need the tables to be tied somehow so that it can check to see if the user has the rights to that song. So that it checks whether the variable is set to 1 in the user table

Comment: You should never do database queries inside a loop.

Comment: Check my edit, I'm recommending a change to the user table to reference the music table. You should also break within the loop as to show only one download and one query to be safe.

Comment: From what I can see, I think the user shouldn't be able to download more than one file at a time, or to better put it, doesn't make sense to allow the user to do so. So actually, a loop is not needed. You're only getting one row, is this correct?

Comment: no, what this is doing is creating a place on the page where they can access any download link they have earned

Comment: Oh! Okay, then I would remove the hash check entirely, since they are logged in, you can just perform the check on the download page. Just have download.php?music_id=1, while 1 is in reference to the music table.

Comment: I use the hash to make a secure download link so that users can't share it. The link expires so users can't share the download.

Comment: Users need to login, so download.php will only work if the user is logged in and has "earned" the music file. So sharing wouldn't work anyway. A hash is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand completely what you want to do, but I assume the following:

You're reading from a table which contains filenames, and for each file you want to create the entry in the table downloads, as well as output the HTML link to the download.

Here's how you could do it, but it looks like you need to change your table structure for the files to something like the following:

```
id  track_no  filename
```

In that case, you could do everything directly in the first loop:

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultstwo))
{
    $strKey = createKey();
    mysqli_query($resDB, 
        "INSERT INTO downloads (downloadkey, file, expires) 
        VALUES(
            $strKey, 
            $row['track_no']." ".$row['filename'], 
            (time()+(60*60))
        )");
    echo "<a href=\"download.php?key=$strKey\">$row['filename']</a>";        
}
```

If that doesn't answer your question, you should tell us more about your table containing the files.

Comment: You should never do database queries inside a loop.

Comment: I didn't want to change the code too much from what the poster was asking for. Clearly just beginning with PHP, let's keep things simple.

Comment: I think you are suggesting the same thing as the other person. The only problem I have now is checking whether or not that user has the variable set in the users table. and @Kao why no queries inside of a loop?

Comment: Because you will be hitting the database multiple times, which is a performance drag. It is much better to build a SQL insert string and insert them all at once.

Comment: See my answer on how to do it by only hitting the DB once.

Comment: I think the above answer now tells you how to link user table with downloads. As for the insert query string buildup, maybe that should go into another question, or most likely that question has already been answered. Basically you build up the query string or fill an array inside the loop, and then execute the query once outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Building on other answers, here's how to do the loop and hit the database only once.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO downloads (downloadkey, file, expires) VALUES ";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultstwo)) {
    $strKey = createKey();
    $time = time()+(60*60);

    $query .= "('{$strKey}', '{$row['filename']}', {$time}),";
    echo "<a href='download.php?key=$strKey'>{$row['caption']}</a>";
}

$query = substr ( $query, 0, -1 ); // Remove the last comma.

mysql_query ( resDB, $query );
```

The end result of the query will be something like:

```
INSERT INTO downloads (downloadkey, file, expires) VALUES 
                      ('adfsdfgsdgs', 'Bladerunner.avi', 12345678),
                      ('dfghfyadfsg', 'How_I_met_your_mother.avi', 12345678),
                      ('34t34t3t', 'Simpson_the_movie.avi', 12345678),
                      ('taert43te', '{$row['filename']}', 12345678),
                      ('at43t3t', '{$row['filename']}', 12345678),
```

This will insert all the values into mysql using this one query only.

Comment: ok, I am trying to figure out how to implement this in with the other answers

Comment: yes this definitely works, now I just need to make it only work if the user has the variable set to 1

Comment: Can you explain a little about the value this user should be setting to 1?

Comment: So I now have two tables, music and users. Music has the filename and link name, and users has the username, password, etc., and then variables like $intro that if set to 1 they have earned the download. There is later code in my file that if they have points they can buy the download and it sets the variable to 1

Comment: So they earn a point to download any file, or a specific file? And do you store these points in the users table?

Comment: they use the points to pick a specific file, for example if they have 100 points they can click the button to buy Intro, the code then sets $intro to 1. They can then at any time come back and download that file. The points are also stored as a variable in the user table.

Comment: So what you need is actually 2 lists, a list of files they've already bought, which can be downloaded, and a list of files available for purchase?

Comment: wait actually I don't think it is working because it is not inserting anything into the table

Comment: I have the full list in the users table, if they have bought the download the variable is set to 1, if they have not it is set to 0

Comment: How do you store if a piece of music has been bought?

Comment: by setting the variable to 1, if they have not bought it the variable is set to 0 which is the default

Comment: Yes, but do you store it in a database, and how?

Comment: yes it is stored in the users table using this mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET fewandfar = 1 WHERE users.user_name = '$username' LIMIT 1")

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
function f($condition, $filename, $prettyname) 
{ 
    if ($condition) 
    {
        $strKey = createKey();
        mysqli_query($resDB,"INSERT INTO downloads (downloadkey, file, expires) VALUES ('{$strKey}', '$filename', '".(time()+(60*60))."')");
        echo "<a href='download.php?key=$strKey'>$prettyname</a>";
    }
}
```

And then simply recover the values from the database, a file or just an array as you see fit.